# How do I decode the x500 address in a bounce message, so I can add it to a user's account?

Tags: exchange-2010, email-bounces

I moved a user's email account, and now cached x500 addresses to the user are failing. How do I translate the x500 in the bounce message to the correct x500 alias I should add to their mailbox?

Bounce text:

```
IMCEAEX-
_O=ORGANIZATION_OU=EXCHANGE+20ADMINISTRATIVE+20GROUP+20+28FYDIBOHF23SPDLT+29_CN=RECIPIENTS_CN=John+20Doeb81@company.com
```

Matching x500 address:

```
/O=ORGANIZATION/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=John Doe
```

I am reasonably certain of the entire translation **except** that `b81` near the end. However this translated x500 address (either with the `b81` included or truncated) does not work for getting mail to properly arrive when I add it to the user. Is there documentation (or even better... a copy-paste translator page) on how to reverse engineer the correct x500 to add to the user so that cached account credentials continue to work?

Comment: what's the user's mailbox alias? usually the alias is the last CN.

Comment: Other than some obscuring of actual names, the code above displays exactly what the mail server returned when it tried to deliver mail to them; while it is not just the CN of the user, it is obviously related to it. The alias for the user is **jdoe**, and matches the beginning of their primary email address (**jdoe@campany.com**). Is that what you meant?

Comment: I can't quite tell from your original question, but have you tried putting b81 at the end? If it was an escape sequence, it would have a plus sign, so I think it's literal.

Comment: You are correct that I did not mention it... but yes, I tried it as a literal, with no result.

Answer (score 1):

After much pain and suffering, our mail admin finally found a translation method that works:

```
IMCEAEX-_O=ORGANIZATION_OU=First+20Administrative+20Group_cn=Recipients_cn=Userb81company.com

/o=ORGANIZATION/ou=First Administrative Group/cn=Recipients/cn=User
```

The issue was case sensitivity; the o=, ou=, and other things are case sensitive and the correct case is not always represented in the error. Very frustrating. I hope this helps someone!